# Can't add a core entity to a link table in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I have created 4 separate core entity tables called **course, module, class, classtype** in a small database in phpMyAdmin and 1 link table called **scheduling** with foreign key constraints to each of these core entity tables, so I can populate the scheduling table via lookup from these 4 tables as I have setup foreign key constraints.

I want to add a new field in scheduling with a foreign key constraint to a 5th core entity table called **room**, but don't know how to do it, Can anyone help please?

SQL code for tables setup below;

```
 CREATE TABLE course
(
course_id int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
course_name varchar(30),
course_director varchar(20),
course_cao_code varchar(7),
course_details varchar(2000),
PRIMARY KEY(course_id)
)
Engine=InnoDB

CREATE TABLE module
(
module_id int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
module_name varchar(20),
module_supervisor varchar(20),
module_details varchar(200),
PRIMARY KEY(module_id)
)
Engine=InnoDB

CREATE TABLE class
(
class_id int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
class_name varchar(6),
class_stage int(1),
class_leisure_room varchar(10),
PRIMARY KEY(class_id)
)
Engine=InnoDB

CREATE TABLE classtype
(
classtype_id int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
classtype_name varchar(8),
classtype_capacity int(3),
PRIMARY KEY(classtype_id)
)
Engine=InnoDB


CREATE TABLE scheduling
(
course_id int(5) NOT NULL,
module_id int(5) NOT NULL,
class_id int(5) NOT NULL,
classtype_id int(5) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (course_id,module_id,class_id,classtype_id)
)
Engine=InnoDB;


CREATE TABLE room
(
room_id int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
room_name varchar(6),
room_capacity int(3),
PRIMARY KEY(room_id)
)
Engine=InnoDB
```